# Rasons for Hebrew text to turn into gibberish

Tags: windows, text, character-encoding

Why will windows display ANSI .txt as gibberish:

```
úâéåú:
ñøè :
÷åì:
```

where it should be:

```
תגיות:
סרט :
קול:
```

If I open the .txt file in Notepad++ and select Encoding, seems like the encoding is ANSI

how did windows get from [ת] to [ú]  anyway?
Any tool that can fix bulk of such files?

Comment: The underlying byte string is `"\xfa\xe2\xe9\xe5\xfa:\n\xf1\xf8\xe8 :\n\xf7\xe5\xec:"`. Decoded as codepage 1252 it's Latin text. Decoded as codepage 1255 it's Hebrew text.

Comment: If that didn't help, please read [the `character-encoding` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Seems to be a windows issue with encoding text... Hebrew is not in the ASCII set